# VS2010 Configuration Manager - keeps setting back to Any CPU

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a few projects that must build as x86.  So we go to the solution, choose Properties-> Configuration Properties->Configuration Manager, set everything to x86, set all projects to build, and we're good to go!

Three days later (more or less) I open the project and it's back to Any CPU, and a mixture of what projects are enabled or not.  In fact this morning I RDP'd into my workstation, edited some code, set these settings to x86.  Then rebooted the machine, went into the office, opened the project and it was back to Any CPU.

What the heck is going on?  I know x86 is not "cool" but we have real reasons for this requirement.

Comment: The configuration name has nothing to do with the setting that matters when this is a managed code solution.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target is what matters.  Change it for all your configurations, just in case.

Comment: But the solution contains projects that are shared.  Those shared ones do compile to x64 for other solutions.  I thought the solution settings overwrote project settings.